# what does the payload of mule message always contain?

Tags: mule

I just need to ask a question about the type of data in mule message?
is it a java object determined by the message source and processors OR a java object implementing the collection interface?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a certification/exam question.

Comment: sorry if it seemed that way but i just wana ask is it in the form of a list or jsut an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand your question. Is related to  : mule message structure?

The Mule message is the data that passes through an application via one or more flows. It consists of two main parts:

**message header** which contains metadata about the message

**message payload** which contains your business-specific data.

Here official documentation:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-fundamentals/v/3.7/mule-message-structure